# MVC Login Partial View Control Return View is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, partial-views

I have a asp.net mvc project and I made a partial view for log in. Every time I try to log in with a wrong password I would like the project to stay on the partial view and then show an errormessage "Wrong username or password." on the partial view. Now it gives me this error:

"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'KipparitRy2._0.Models.Logins', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'KipparitRy2._0.Models.Client'."

And I don't want the type to be of course a client, but to use Logins. I don't understand why this comes..

My controller (in HomeController):

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Authorize(Logins LoginModel)
        {
            var LoggedUser = db.Logins.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username== LoginModel.Kayttajanimi && x.Password == LoginModel.Password);
            if (LoggedUser != null)
            {
                ViewBag.LoggedStatus = "In";
                ViewBag.LoginError = 0;
                Session["Username"] = LoggedUser.Username;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.LoggedStatus = "Out";
                ViewBag.LoginError = 1;
                LoginModel.ErrorMessage = "Wrong username or password.";
                return View("Index", LoginModel);
            }
        }
```

If I change return View to this: `return PartialView("_LoginModal", LoginModel);` then it kinda works, but it opens the partial view to a new window (not view), and that I don't want.

Here's my login class:

```
    public partial class Logins
    {
        public int LoginID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Give a username!")]
        public string Kayttajanimi { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Give a password!")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's my _LoginModal.cshtml:

```
@model OfficeRy2._0.Models.Logins

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Log in</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Authorize", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Username</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)  </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <label class="field-validation-error">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ErrorMessage)</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="name" class="btn btn-success" value="Log" />
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Help is needed...

Comment: you are returning model `return View("Index", LoginModel);` but on the view page you have `@model OfficeRy2._0.Models.Logins` so you need to return model Logins instead of LoginModel

Comment: I don't understand how... I tried returning the partial view, but it didn't work.

Comment: partial views aren't for modals... they're just includes... (useful when you re-use view components, or just to breakup pieces of the view/markup): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

issue is that your main page either does not have any model or its model is different from your partial model. If you want to retain the state of your page then you need to wither use AJAX form or simply make middle model that holds your login model and pass that to your main view.